# How to make a UIView always appear at the front?

Tags: iphone, uiview

Currently I have a UIView which contains some controls. I then have some images I programatically add to the view to display as animations. Currently at the end of each interval of my game loop im having to tell the controller to move the UIView control to the front, otherwise the images will appear on top of it. Is there a less costly method of making it persist as always on top.

**Currently I have the following at the end of my game loop:**

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myControlView];
```

**Could I do something like this when the game initiates:**

```
myControlView.alwaysOnTop = true;
```

Comment: I just came across the same issue. I wanted to have an UIImageView in front of all my views (complex addition of Navigation / Page View, etc) to display a tutorial.

I had to mix up a few things to get it work. In fact, i used both : `bringSubviewToFront:` and `view.layer.zPosition=MAXFLOAT` It might help someone !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Rather than using `-addSubview:` to insert your images, use `-insertSubview:belowSubview:` and pass your `UIView` as the second parameter:

```
[self.view insertSubview:myImage belowSubview:myControlView];
```

Note that for similar purposes you also have access to the methods `-insertSubview:aboveSubview:` and `-insertSubview:atIndex:`.

Answer (score 200):

**Objective-C**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
myAlwaysOnTopView.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;
```

**Swift 2**

```
myAlwaysOnTopView.layer.zPosition = .max
```

**Swift 3**

```
myAlwaysOnTopView.layer.zPosition = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
```

**Swift 5.3**

```
view.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

This solution is better, especially if you want your view to be always on top, regardless of other views added after it. Just add any other view using `addSubview:` and it will always remains on top.

**IMPORTANT:** this solution will make the UIView *appear* on top, but it will still be below other views for the UI system. That is, any user interaction with the view will generally not work, because it is handled by other overlapping views first.

Comment: It works for me on iOS 7.1. but I lose touch when the VC gets added (shown). Setting the userInteractionEnabled to YES , didn't help.

Comment: I had to use `myView.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)`

Comment: `CGFloat.max` has been renamed in swift 3 to `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude`

Comment: doesn't wok when there's a popup dialog or alert shown up

Comment: While this solution works for sheer visibility,  it does not guarantee that it will override touches for any element that is 'underneath' it (that is the case at least for any Gesture Recognizer).

Comment: This will not work if you adding views after this line was executed. Isn't that the whole point ?

Comment: working fine but " CoreAnimation: zPosition should be within (-FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX) range." is printing on console

Comment: It's work for the only display view. for action or gesture need to add a view on windows.

Comment: This should be view.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude) to avoid "CoreAnimation: zPosition should be within (-FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX) range"

Comment: I love how every version does it differently. The only thing consistent between versions of Swift is the name.

Answer (score 3):

The other option is to place your view on another UIWindow with higher windowLevel. Learn from [Flipboard FLEX](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX) or my simplified [Paramount](https://github.com/onmyway133/ftgparamount)

```
Manager.action = {
  print("action touched")
}

Manager.show()
```

Take a look at the [FLEXWindow](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX/blob/master/Classes/Explorer%20Toolbar/FLEXWindow.m) on how to choose proper windowLevel and handle touch

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        // Some apps have windows at UIWindowLevelStatusBar + n.
        // If we make the window level too high, we block out UIAlertViews.
        // There's a balance between staying above the app's windows and staying below alerts.
        // UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 100 seems to hit that balance.
        self.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 100.0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    BOOL pointInside = NO;
    if ([self.eventDelegate shouldHandleTouchAtPoint:point]) {
        pointInside = [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
    }
    return pointInside;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to make a subview move to the back of all other current subviews, use `view.sendSubviewToBack(yourSubview)`.

Answer (score 0):

just remember there is this method too,

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view aboveSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create an invisible container view for all your other views. Add that container view first to your main view, and the UIView you want to have on top after that. Then add all your other views to the container view, instead of to the main view.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest, safest solution. Cheers.