# send programmatic UIView to back against UIView added in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm creating UIView programmatically and called this `UIView captureImage`. This `UIView captureImage` display the image that I capture from camera and the parentView I called it `self.frameForCapture`. But the problem is, It always overlap the UIView that I add to the storyboard.

Update Post:

Here is the image that I'm trying to make in my app.
[image]

Black View is my parentView and I called it self.frameForCapture.
Blue View is childView, and I add it using the storyboard.
Red View is childView, and I programmatically added to the parentView.
But the time I add it the redView. It always overlap the blueView, i use this `addSubView:`.
But if I used these

```
[self.frameForCapture bringSubviewToFront:captureImage]; 
[self.frameForCapture sendSubviewToBack:captureImage];
```

nothing happen.
I used this code:

```
self.newalbumImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.newalbumImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
 self.newalbumImageView.image = self.albumImage;
UIView * captureImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frameForCapture.frame];
[captureImage addSubview:self.newalbumImageView];
[self.frameForCapture addSubview:captureImage];
```

Comment: It is possible but you need to make your view hierarchy clearer. This doesn't give enough information of exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: sorry I will update my post.

Comment: Are you sure `captureImage` is a child of `frameForCapture`? You also said "They have the same parentView."

Comment: Yes. the captureImage is a child of frameForCapture

Comment: I update my post. hoping for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

there are a few things that can help you look at this question [How to make a UIView always appear at the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511443/how-to-make-a-uiview-always-appear-at-the-front)
just link the headerview to .h file and use `myAlwaysOnTopView.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;`
another thing is that when you use `[self.frameForCapture sendSubviewToBack:captureImage];`
the redview will still be on top of `self.frameForCapture` if don't want it like that you can hide it or even remove
if you still have  this problem just tag me